# How to show empty value in place of undefined value in JSON api?

Tags: javascript

In weather api, some values are null which is displayed as undefined on main page (See the image at the bottom), which takes maximum space.
How to replace these null values with empty i.e '  ' or 'NA'?

Below is the code

```
fetch(`${IP_LOCATION}&lat=${lat}&long=${lon}`)
  .then(res => res.json()).then(responseJson => {
    try {
      this.setState({
        sunrise: responseJson.sunrise,
        sunset: responseJson.sunset,
        // Here I get undefined
        moonrise: responseJson.moonrise,
        moonset: responseJson.moonset,
      })

    } catch {
      toast.error('No Data Received')
    }

  });
```

[image]

Any solution?

Answer (score 4):

quick solution:

```
try {
      this.setState({
        sunrise: responseJson.sunrise,
        sunset: responseJson.sunset,

        // replace with this line 
        moonrise: responseJson.moonrise ? responseJson.moonrise : " ",

        moonset: responseJson.moonset,
      })

    } catch {
      toast.error('No Data Received')
    }
```

(edit)
using the ternary operator you can check for null or undefined and override with value of your choice

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think `A ? A : B` is an elvis operator, but a basic ternary. Elvis is `A ?: B` isn't it?

Comment: Hey guys... Its still returning undefined

Comment: I tried with the solution mentioned by @GiuseppeB, but, still no effect

Comment: any chance is a binding issue? what if you replace "" with any char, as "-"?

Comment: you can try to bind the var using the elvis operator (this time elvis for real) .
{{state?.moonrise}}

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ternary operator as @GiuseppeB mentioned. Or you can use an `or` operator like this `responseJson.moonrise || ""`. Keep in mind with this solution, however, that if `responseJson.moonrise` is ever a falsy value (not just `null` or `undefined`) then the empty string will be the result.